# My contenteditable div always tells me that the last word is misspelled in Firefox, why?

Tags: html, firefox, contenteditable

Somehow, in my website, the last word appearing in a `contenteditable` is marked as misspelled, even when it is the correct spelling.

Here is an example of such an entry with the last word clearly marked as misspelled:

[image]

Just in case there is the HTML code surrounding that contenteditable `<div>` tag.

[image]

- *Note: as mentioned by Carl below, that screenshot shows the HTML as loaded and not the HTML as used once jQuery ran against it. I have a simplified sample below that includes that data. Also it shows a `!` at the end of the string, which makes it work right... (Any other character after the word, and the spelling works fine.)*

I tried to replicate that problem in jsfiddle without luck, so I create a simplified version of the page with just that one widget:

http://alexis.m2osw.com/contenteditable/ContentEditableProblemSimplified.html

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** On first load, it works properly because Firefox does not check the spelling of words at that time. You have to click in that field once and the effect happens.

This happens in FireFox v53.0, it has been like that for a while though.

Comment: Does it only happen in a `contenteditable` element? Or is it the same in a textarea for example? This probably doesn't help answer the question, just curious and attempting to limit possibilities.

Comment: I have always seen it in `contenteditable` but never in `input` or `textarea`. Also notice that I put nothing after the last word (i.e. no period or exclamation mark) because anything there and it works fine...

Comment: The div in the source doesn't have a `contenteditable` attribute. Are you using a JS library to convert anything with a specified class to `contenteditable`?

Comment: You also mention that *I put nothing after the last word*, yet there is an exclamation mark in the source. The question doesn't really have a lot to go on. What version of FF are you using? Could you post the actual HTML rather than a screenshot of the HTML rendered in the browser (pref the whole HTML of the page)

Comment: @CarlMarkham, it's in a CMS I am writing... I removed the `!` in my test, but I suppose I can try to save the page and see how that works. If it fails there, it may be a good sample to test the problem.

Comment: @CarlMarkham Okay, that simplified page I saved on my personal website fails as expected. The HTML is "only" 8567 bytes, so will be easier to deal with. However, I kept the formatting (or non-formatting?) as the CMS generates the code. I was thinking that jsfiddle may not regenerate the problem because they always add some spaces by indenting the code cleanly (maybe).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143449/discussion-between-carl-markham-and-alexis-wilke).